# Linear algebra eigenvalue proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I asked this question before but after thinking about it I was trying to think of another way. [Proof multiplied complex matrix has non negative eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039085/proof-multiplied-complex-matrix-has-non-negative-eigenvalues)
I need to show given that A is a matrix $\in \mathbb{C^{nxn}}$ that
AA* has eigenvalues >0

My attempt:
let $\mathbf x$ be the eigenvector for AA*
 =< AA*$\mathbf x$, $\mathbf x$ >
=< A*$\mathbf x$, A*$\mathbf x$ >
 = $||A^*\mathbf x||^2$
 =$\lambda^* ||\mathbf x||^2$
Therefore since $||A^*\mathbf x||^2$ = $\lambda^* ||\mathbf x||^2$
$\lambda$ is >0

I was wondering if this solution is also correct, if not please tell me the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^*$ with corresponding eigenvector $x$, then
$$\lambda\|x\|^2=\lambda\langle x,x\rangle=\langle \lambda x,x\rangle=\langle AA^*x,x\rangle=\langle A^*x,A^*x\rangle=\|A^*x\|^2>0$$
and hence $\lambda>0$.

Comment: So is the error in my solution that I didn't say ||A*x||> 0? Thanks

Comment: Reading back, I don't think you really had an error. I saw your line $\|A^*x\|^2=\lambda^*\|x\|^2$ and assumed they were intended to follow on from one another, but the latter line in fact comes from the first step (much like in my proof).

So yeah, your answer is good. Maybe just make your setting out just slightly clearer.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot!